# Having trouble with background worker processes in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf

I found a few other articles regarding using background worker which I've linked just below. I used the code examples and attempted to do this to run 3 different SQL Query's.  In the code posted below when I break inside of RunBackGroundWorkerProcesses1 it does stop there and is called but method for worker_DoWork1 is never called even though it is in the code. I'm assuming that I've misunderstood this, can someone add some clarity.

Link I used for reference:
[WPF Multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869796/wpf-multithreading)

Code:

```
public CallInformationMainScreen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();    

//This is where i call the background processes
            RunBackGroundWorkerProcesses1();
            RunBackGroundWorkerProcesses2();
            RunBackGroundWorkerProcesses3();    
        }
        #endregion

        #region Methods used to generate data for the UI
        public string DisplayTotalDailyCalls()
        {
            DailyCallsQuery db = new DailyCallsQuery();
            return db.GetNumber(SkillNumber);
        }
        public string DisplayTotalLastSevenCalls()
        {
            PrevSevenCallQuery db = new PrevSevenCallQuery();
            return db.GetNumber(SkillNumber);
        }
        public string DisplayDailyAbandonCalls()
        {
            DailyAbandonQuery db = new DailyAbandonQuery();
            return db.GetNumber(SkillNumber);
        }    


        #endregion

        #region Background worker processes        
        private void RunBackGroundWorkerProcesses1()
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();            
            worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork1);
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);

            System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(10000); //  10 second intervals
            t.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
            {
                // Don't try to start the work if it's still busy with the previous run...
                if (!worker.IsBusy)
                    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
            };
        }
        private void RunBackGroundWorkerProcesses2()
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();           
            worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork2);
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);

            System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(10000); //  10 second intervals
            t.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
            {
                // Don't try to start the work if it's still busy with the previous run...
                if (!worker.IsBusy)
                    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
            };
        }
        private void RunBackGroundWorkerProcesses3()
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();            
            worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork3);
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);

            System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(10000); //  10 second intervals
            t.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
            {
                // Don't try to start the work if it's still busy with the previous run...
                if (!worker.IsBusy)
                    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
            };
        }

        private void worker_DoWork1(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            // Whatever comes back from the lengthy process, we can put into e.Result            
            TotalDailyCalls = DisplayTotalDailyCalls();
            e.Result = TotalDailyCalls;
        }
        private void worker_DoWork2(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            // Whatever comes back from the lengthy process, we can put into e.Result            
            TotalDailyLast7Days = DisplayTotalLastSevenCalls();
            e.Result = TotalDailyCalls;
        }
        private void worker_DoWork3(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            // Whatever comes back from the lengthy process, we can put into e.Result
            TotalDailyAbandon = DisplayDailyAbandonCalls();
            e.Result = TotalDailyAbandon;
        }

        private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // First, handle the case where an exception was thrown.
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                // handle the System.Exception
                MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
            }
            else if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                // now handle the case where the operation was cancelled... 
                ErrorHolder = "The operation was cancelled";
            }
            else
            {
                // Finally, handle the case where the operation succeeded
                ErrorHolder = e.Result.ToString();
            }
        }
        #endregion
```

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do with this code? Is it simply that you're trying to repeatedly run each of these three queries in the background?

Comment: yes the numbers are calls coming into call queue and will update every few minutes. i was going to adjust the time after i got it to at least function which it looks like it is doing now thanks to the answer below and the simple timer start that i missed.

Comment: There's a far simply way to do this. I'll pop an answer in for you to show you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't start your timers. See [Timer.Start Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.start(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
    private void RunBackGroundWorkerProcesses1()
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();            
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork1);
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);

        System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(10000); //  10 second intervals
        t.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
        {
            // Don't try to start the work if it's still busy with the previous run...
            if (!worker.IsBusy)
                worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        };
        t.Start(); // Start the timer
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this to demonstrate an easier way to do this. It's not meant to be a direct answer to the question.

If you NuGet "System.Reactive" and the associated WPF libraries you can do this:

```
IDisposable subscription =
    new []
    {
        Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0)).Select(x => DisplayTotalDailyCalls()),
        Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0)).Select(x => DisplayTotalLastSevenCalls()),
        Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0)).Select(x => DisplayDailyAbandonCalls()),
    }
    .Merge()
    .ObserveOnDispatcher()
    .Subscribe(x => ErrorHolder = x, e => MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message));
```

That's it. Job done. All of your code in techically one line of code.

Comment: holy crap. lol. Just to understand this correctly, that replaces all three of my background worker methods? And this still allows them to operate as a background process? The reason for all this is because each time one of these SQL methods were triggered it would lock the application. so i need to be sure that the querys are happening as a background process.

Comment: actually this will also replace my completed and all my dowork methods too. wow.

Comment: @mrcavanaugh09 - Yes, that's correct. All in the background. All with a 10 second gap between each run, all running in parallel, and all replacing all the methods in your code.

Comment: @mrcavanaugh09 - If you want to stop the code running just call `subscription.Dispose();`.

Answer (score 0):

`BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()` is only called when the `Timer.Elapsed` event is fired. Since the timer is set to 10 second intervals, the `BackgroundWorker` won't start for 10 seconds. You probably should call `BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()` after creating and initializing it so that it will start right away.

Comment: backgroundworker.runworkerasync() is called in the if statement in each method already. I've also waited minutes with the application running and none of the SQL Query methods are being hit.